# Excel Auto Attendance sheet

Tags: excel, windows, forms, command, time-and-attendance

im trying to make an automatic attendance sheet here are the details:
-Data will be imported in the excel sheet (left side)
-I want to automatically mark "p" or "a" a specific cell based on the data imported

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since you're trying to check several conditions at the same time (date, time, id) in your source data I'd recommend normalizing the time to the start of the hour,

[START OF HOUR FUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXGs8.png)

then adding a unique value for each you could concatenate "DATE", "TIME", "ID" with some type of separator for example "-"

[CONCAT FUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMMOZ.png)

and then you could try with using a lookup function to look for that specific value,

[LOOKUP FUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOYsK.png)

with an IF function so that if the value is returned you print p or if false print a.

[IF FUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4t7V.png)

Comment: Actually, I have done a few developments regarding this question, i already formulated a the command for marking "p" and "a", Now the problem is the time constraints, another mark "l" for late. the problem im facing right now is how do i evaluate wether the time is within a certain range. Here is the link to the file im working on (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1edOB2Jcxt0NCywZNj4YLiCcgG0LKnGFP/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117782945819933885815&rtpof=true&sd=true)